# Angular Bootstrap is clearing has-error CSS class after field is valid but cleared at once

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in my page to show errors when a field is invalid based on ng validations. I first enter the field data and if it is incorrect, the error message is showing with `has-error` css.

[image: Initially when field is dirty and invalid]

[image: Field is dirty and valid]

After it went green, I selected and removed all the text in the box at once, the error message is showing but it doesn't contain `has-error` css applied. Looks like when I clear the field, `has-error` is also cleared. The error message is showing in the `help-block` CSS color. Why does this happen ?

[image: Field is dirty and invalid but cleared from valid state]

```
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-3 control-label text-sm text-left"
                                   translate="register.form.email">Email Address</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address (Username)" class="form-control"
                                       ng-model="registerAccount.email" required name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail"
                                       minlength="4" maxlength="255">
                                <div
                                    ng-show="form.inputEmail.$dirty && form.inputEmail.$invalid && form.inputEmail.$touched">
                                    <p class="has-error help-block nile-help-block"
                                       ng-show="form.inputEmail.$error.required"
                                       translate="register.messages.validate.login.email.required">
                                        Your e-mail address is required.
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="has-error help-block nile-help-block"
                                       ng-show="form.inputEmail.$error.email"
                                       translate="register.messages.validate.login.email.invalid">
                                        Your e-mail is in invalid format. eg: abc@example.com
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="has-error help-block nile-help-block"
                                       ng-show="form.inputEmail.$error.minlength"
                                       translate="register.messages.validate.login.email.minlength">
                                        Your e-mail is required to be at least 4 characters including @.
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="has-error help-block nile-help-block"
                                       ng-show="form.inputEmail.$error.maxlength"
                                       translate="register.messages.validate.login.email.maxlength">
                                        Your e-mail cannot be longer than 255 characters.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

`nile-help-block` has only font size related css. Rest all are bootstrap classes.

Comment: I don't understand why this is not working either, but I think there is a pretty simple way to make it work and improve your code at the same time. In all of your `<p>`, the `class` attribute is the same. Try to move this `class` attribute to the containing `<div>`. It might solve your issue, and help your code stay DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: that doesnt help either. That is what I initially had and broke it down to see if it helps.